# How to use string functions in the ON clause of a LEFT JOIN with standard SQL in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around using a string function such as `STARTS_WITH` or an operator such as `LIKE` in a `LEFT JOIN ON` where the parameters of either come from both tables in the join. Rather than try to explain the abstracts, I've distilled a small example ...

Let's consider a table called **fuzzylog** that has a key field `fullname` that I want to canonicalize by joining to a **names** table that has the same column. The key field in fuzzylog may be a bit messy or free-form so a direct equality join is not possible. These tables might look something like this:

`fuzzylog` table:

[image: fuzzylog table]

`names` table:

[image: names table]

The names table tries to accomodate the fuzziness by providing a `contains` field which I want to join on using `LIKE` should the exact match fail:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT l.id, n.fullname, n.nameid,
  l.fullname AS logged_fullname
FROM `neilotemp.fuzzylog` l
LEFT JOIN `neilotemp.names` n
  ON l.fullname = n.fullname
  OR l.fullname LIKE CONCAT('%', n.contains, '%')
```

Unfortunately that last line, the one I really need, causes the error: **LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.** This is really what I'm trying to solve.

I've done quite a few searches but haven't been able to find anything that is getting it to click in my head. I must be one conceptual step off from the right path.

Comment: When BigQuery doesn't allow non-equi-joins you're out of luck. Did you try an Inner Join instead?

Comment: Try using CROSS JOIN with WHERE instead. The condition you've provided can't be used to execute a hash join.

Comment: What do you want to return when a name matches multiple `contains`?

Comment: @dnoeth Ideally it would take only the first/best match but I realize my example is not setup to handle that. Mainly I wanted to figure out how to do a `LEFT JOIN` (the possibility of no match without it excluding the record) but I did try with `INNER JOIN` and you're correct that it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I think using `contains` field is not the best idea here
Instead consider below approach with using Levenshtein [edit] distance

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION EDIT_DISTANCE(string1 STRING, string2 STRING)
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var _extend = function(dst) {
    var sources = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    for (var i=0; i<sources.length; ++i) {
      var src = sources[i];
      for (var p in src) {
        if (src.hasOwnProperty(p)) dst[p] = src[p];
      }
    }
    return dst;
  };

  var Levenshtein = {
    /**
     * Calculate levenshtein distance of the two strings.
     *
     * @param str1 String the first string.
     * @param str2 String the second string.
     * @return Integer the levenshtein distance (0 and above).
     */
    get: function(str1, str2) {
      // base cases
      if (str1 === str2) return 0;
      if (str1.length === 0) return str2.length;
      if (str2.length === 0) return str1.length;

      // two rows
      var prevRow  = new Array(str2.length + 1),
          curCol, nextCol, i, j, tmp;

      // initialise previous row
      for (i=0; i<prevRow.length; ++i) {
        prevRow[i] = i;
      }

      // calculate current row distance from previous row
      for (i=0; i<str1.length; ++i) {
        nextCol = i + 1;

        for (j=0; j<str2.length; ++j) {
          curCol = nextCol;

          // substution
          nextCol = prevRow[j] + ( (str1.charAt(i) === str2.charAt(j)) ? 0 : 1 );
          // insertion
          tmp = curCol + 1;
          if (nextCol > tmp) {
            nextCol = tmp;
          }
          // deletion
          tmp = prevRow[j + 1] + 1;
          if (nextCol > tmp) {
            nextCol = tmp;
          }

          // copy current col value into previous (in preparation for next iteration)
          prevRow[j] = curCol;
        }

        // copy last col value into previous (in preparation for next iteration)
        prevRow[j] = nextCol;
      }

      return nextCol;
    }

  };

  var the_string1;

  try {
    the_string1 = decodeURI(string1).toLowerCase();
  } catch (ex) {
    the_string1 = string1.toLowerCase();
  }

  try {
    the_string2 = decodeURI(string2).toLowerCase();
  } catch (ex) {
    the_string2 = string2.toLowerCase();
  }

  return Levenshtein.get(the_string1, the_string2) 

""";   
WITH notrmalized_fuzzylog as (
  select id, fullname, 
    (select string_agg(part, ' ' order by part) from unnest(split(fullname, ' ')) part) ordered_fullname
  from `project.dataset.fuzzylog`
), normalized_names as (
  select nameid, fullname, 
    (select string_agg(part, ' ' order by part) from unnest(split(fullname, ' ')) part) ordered_fullname
  from `project.dataset.names`
)
select
  id, l.fullname AS logged_fullname,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(n.nameid, n.fullname)
    ORDER BY EDIT_DISTANCE(l.ordered_fullname, n.ordered_fullname) LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM notrmalized_fuzzylog l
CROSS JOIN normalized_names n
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION EDIT_DISTANCE(string1 STRING, string2 STRING)
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var _extend = function(dst) {
    var sources = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    for (var i=0; i<sources.length; ++i) {
      var src = sources[i];
      for (var p in src) {
        if (src.hasOwnProperty(p)) dst[p] = src[p];
      }
    }
    return dst;
  };

  var Levenshtein = {
    /**
     * Calculate levenshtein distance of the two strings.
     *
     * @param str1 String the first string.
     * @param str2 String the second string.
     * @return Integer the levenshtein distance (0 and above).
     */
    get: function(str1, str2) {
      // base cases
      if (str1 === str2) return 0;
      if (str1.length === 0) return str2.length;
      if (str2.length === 0) return str1.length;

      // two rows
      var prevRow  = new Array(str2.length + 1),
          curCol, nextCol, i, j, tmp;

      // initialise previous row
      for (i=0; i<prevRow.length; ++i) {
        prevRow[i] = i;
      }

      // calculate current row distance from previous row
      for (i=0; i<str1.length; ++i) {
        nextCol = i + 1;

        for (j=0; j<str2.length; ++j) {
          curCol = nextCol;

          // substution
          nextCol = prevRow[j] + ( (str1.charAt(i) === str2.charAt(j)) ? 0 : 1 );
          // insertion
          tmp = curCol + 1;
          if (nextCol > tmp) {
            nextCol = tmp;
          }
          // deletion
          tmp = prevRow[j + 1] + 1;
          if (nextCol > tmp) {
            nextCol = tmp;
          }

          // copy current col value into previous (in preparation for next iteration)
          prevRow[j] = curCol;
        }

        // copy last col value into previous (in preparation for next iteration)
        prevRow[j] = nextCol;
      }

      return nextCol;
    }

  };

  var the_string1;

  try {
    the_string1 = decodeURI(string1).toLowerCase();
  } catch (ex) {
    the_string1 = string1.toLowerCase();
  }

  try {
    the_string2 = decodeURI(string2).toLowerCase();
  } catch (ex) {
    the_string2 = string2.toLowerCase();
  }

  return Levenshtein.get(the_string1, the_string2) 

""";   
WITH `project.dataset.fuzzylog` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'John Smith' fullname UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Jane Doe' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Ms. Jane Doe' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Mr. John Smith' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Smith, John' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'J.Smith' UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'J. Doe'
), `project.dataset.names` AS (
  SELECT 1 nameid, 'John Smith' fullname, 'smith' match UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Jane Doe', 'doe'
), notrmalized_fuzzylog as (
  select id, fullname, 
    (select string_agg(part, ' ' order by part) from unnest(split(fullname, ' ')) part) ordered_fullname
  from `project.dataset.fuzzylog`
), normalized_names as (
  select nameid, fullname, 
    (select string_agg(part, ' ' order by part) from unnest(split(fullname, ' ')) part) ordered_fullname
  from `project.dataset.names`
)
select
  id, l.fullname AS logged_fullname,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(n.nameid, n.fullname)
    ORDER BY EDIT_DISTANCE(l.ordered_fullname, n.ordered_fullname) LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM notrmalized_fuzzylog l
CROSS JOIN normalized_names n
GROUP BY 1, 2
-- ORDER BY 1
```

with result:

```
Row id  logged_fullname nameid  fullname     
1   1   John Smith      1       John Smith   
2   2   Jane Doe        2       Jane Doe     
3   3   Ms. Jane Doe    2       Jane Doe     
4   4   Mr. John Smith  1       John Smith   
5   5   Smith, John     1       John Smith   
6   6   J.Smith         1       John Smith   
7   7   J. Doe          2       Jane Doe
```

As you can see in this solution we totally ignore/remove use of any extra artificial columns (like `contains`) and rather applying Levenshtein distance to measure similarity directly between two fullnames. And as you can see before doing this we reorder/normalizing fullnames to order their parts
If this approach will work for you  - you should consider improving that reordering by first removing/replacing all punctuation like dots, commas, etc with space for better result

Comment: Thank you, this is great info for fuzzy matching. I realize that `LIKE`'ing a column is not the best approach; my question was more specifically about being able to use `LEFT JOIN` with string functions taking parameters from both sides of the join. I would really like to try out the code here but I'm getting *SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at edit_distance(STRING, STRING) line 2, columns 6-13*. Perhaps I don't have user functions enabled or some such?

Comment: are you running the whole code including `#standardSQL` and cretate func lines?

Comment: oh, just a sec - i might had some copy-paste issue - let me double check the code I provided in my answer - give me few min

Comment: Please try now and let me know if still issue in running - as I thought there was some issue when I copy-pasted code from my UI to SO

Comment: It works now; I saw the uppercase and then saw your comment and I think I see what the error was complaining about before. This is very cool. The only issue I see is that if there is a name that is way off and clearly doesn't match, it still has a distance and therefore matches one of them. I could probably rig up some distance threshold so complete misses don't match anything

Comment: exactly - you can use minimum distance that would play role of filter glad you found this useful :o)

Answer (score 2):

You can get this to work with arrays and correlated subqueries:

```
with fuzzylog as (
      select 1 as id, 'John Smith' as fullname union all
      select 2 as id, 'Jane Doe' UNION ALL
      select 6 as id, 'J. Smith'
     ),
     names as (
      select 1 as nameid, 'John Smith' as fullname, 'smith' as word
     )
select l.id, l.fullname, n.fullname as name_fullname, n.nameid
from (SELECT l.*, 
             (SELECT array_agg(n.nameid)
              from names n
              where l.fullname = n.fullname OR lower(l.fullname) LIKE CONCAT('%', lower(n.word), '%')  
             ) nameids
       FROM fuzzylog l
      ) l LEFT JOIN
      unnest(l.nameids) the_nameid left join
      names n
      on n.nameid = the_nameid;
```

Comment: The nesting and cross joins still confuse me but this works to a point. Like an `INNER JOIN` however it excludes records which find no match

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I wonder why the ORed condition is allowed in a Scalar Subquery, which is quite similar to an Outer Join.

Comment: @NeilC.Obremski . . . `UNNEST()` works with `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @dnoeth . . . I can only speculate.  BQ probably optimizes the `LEFT JOIN` to partition the data based on the equality `JOIN` key.  With a scalar subquery, it probably uses a more flexible optimization plan, but at the expense of performance.

Comment: Ah! Sadly, running the newly-edited query now results in the "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join".